# Save the data from a variable for when the function restarts

Tags: python

I wrote a code that presents me a input that i have to guess the fruit, if i guess the fruit my guesses variable gets +1 but then when i type "yes" to the input that will restart the game so that i type another fruit the guesses variable gets reseted back to zero. I tried doing a .write file to save it to an external file but it also didnt work.

```
import random


x = ["banana", "pineapple", "mango"]

def restart():
    guesses
    al = ['yes', 'no']
    r = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no with lower case letters): ")
    if r == "yes":
      game()
    elif r == "no":
      exit()
    else:
      print("Sorry i didn't get that.")
      restart()
    

 

def game():
 gf = open('guesses.txt', 'w')
 global guesses
 guesses = 0
 y = input("Guess the fruit: ")
 z = random.choice(x)


 if y == z:
    
    guesses += 1
    gf.write(str(guesses))
    print("Your answer was correct, you now have:", guesses)
    restart()
 else:
     guesses = guesses 
     print("Your answer was wrong, you now have:", guesses)
     restart()


game()
```

Any help appreciated!

Expected: variable to be saved in external file so it stays after re-execution
Tried: Variable saved after function gets re-executed.
Result: Variable didnt get saved

**EDIT**

I solved it, this is the code i have now:

```
import random

guesses = 0
x = ["banana", "pineapple", "mango"]

def restart():
    guesses
    al = ['yes', 'no']
    r = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no with lower case letters): ")
    if r == "yes":
      game()
    elif r == "no":
      exit()
    else:
      print("Sorry i didn't get that.")
      restart()
    

 

def game():
 gf = open('guesses.txt', 'w')
 y = input("Guess the fruit: ")
 z = random.choice(x)
 global guesses

 if y == z:
    
    guesses += 1
    gf.write(str(guesses))
    print("Your answer was correct, you now have:", guesses)
    restart()
 else:
     if guesses > 0: guesses -= 1
     print("Your answer was wrong, you now have:", guesses)
     if guesses == 0:
      restart()
 gf.close()



game()
```

Comment: You don't close your file after writing to it.

Comment: One obvious problem is that you're trying to recurse to restart the game, when you should be using a loop.  Do you really want to grow the stack each time you start a new game?  If so, why?

Comment: Well i dont remember how to do loops. I am doing this to like remember the basics of python. I will have to study loops again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @LoukasPap said, you need to close the file when you're done. You can either adding `gf.close()` to the end of your `game()` function, or wrapping your code with

```
with open('guesses.txt', 'w') as gf:
    # your code
```

The walrus operation is not necessary here. Even when the variable gets saved into the file, you will also need to read the value from the file, which I believe is such a bad way to do this simple task. Instead, you need to define `guesses` as a global variable by putting it outside of your `game()` function. Besides, I believe you only want to ask the player to end the game when they have no more guesses, and subtract one guess if they got the wrong answer. I re-wrote the code as follow:

```
import random

guesses = 0
x = ["banana", "pineapple", "mango"]

def restart():
    r = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no with lower case letters): ")
    if r == "yes":
      game()
    elif r == "no":
      exit()
    else:
      print("Sorry i didn't get that.")
      restart()
    

def game():
 global guesses
 guesses = 0
 y = input("Guess the fruit: ")
 z = random.choice(x)


 if y == z:
    guesses += 1
    gf.write(str(guesses))
    print("Your answer was correct, you now have:", guesses)
 else:
    guesses -= 1
    print("Your answer was wrong, you now have:", guesses)
    if guesses == 0:        
        restart()

game()
```

### Update

No, you don't need guesses as a global variable. just defining it in the `game()` function should be enough.

Comment: There are still problems with this code, like using recursion where loops should be used.

Comment: Alright i will change some things you said and then i will just go learn loops since it is far better and easier i guess! thanks for answering man

Comment: @TomKarzes You're right, a while loop would look better here. Recursion with exit() works just the same way here (as OP approached this method first), I also recommend using a while loop here.